# VB.net BindingNavigator refresh current records

Tags: vb.net, dataset, bindingnavigator

I'm trying to get my bindingnavigator to "refresh" and show me the new data after I update a record.

I have a Winform with 4 fields (ID, Notes, SN, Cause) and a BindingNavigator1.

- I set the navigator to bindingsource.
- open a connection.
- Set up my tableadapter.
- Set my dataset.
- Add my table.
- Fill my tableadapter.
- Set bindingsource.datasource to ds.table(x)
- Add databindings to the text/comboboxes
- close connection

All this works fine.  I pull data from my DB.  I can scroll through the records fine using the navigator.

Now, when I update one of my records with the Cause combobox, it can affect other records via an UPDATE statement.  This works fine, it runs the UPDATE command and sets the field correctly in the DB for all records that should be updated, but as I'm scrolling through the records with the BindingNavigator, the new data isn't represented in other records.  It's fine in the current record.

I've tried all kinds of combinations of refreshing the bindingnavigator, etc.  here's some of the things I've tried with no luck.

- BindingNavigator1.Refresh()
- BindingSource1.ResetBindings(True)
- Me.UpdateDataSources()
- BindingSource1.ResetBindings(False)
- Me.BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = Me.BindingSource1
- Me.BindingNavigator1.Refresh() 'no go

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is simply re-set the datasource of your `bindingsource`.  Re-read the data from the database after your update, and set those results as the `datasource`.

```
var dbData = GetMyDbData();
BindingSource1.DataSource = dbData;
```

Then as you navigate records using the `bindingnavigator`, you should see all changes in the updated record and any other records updated as a result.